# Duplicate Key with CascadeType.ALL while inserting multiple tables in Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring application and in one of the Controllers lies a `POST` method that allows a user to create multiple entities at once, since they're all related with one main entity, `EncodingResult`.

After testing a bit, it seemed that this caused the following error: `object references an unsaved transient instance`. Looking around a bit, I found that the solution to it was to use `CascadeType.ALL` on the attributes that have `@JoinColumn` annotations in this main class, as such:

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codec", referencedColumnName = "commit_hash", nullable = false)
    private Codec codec;
```

The `Codec` side is as follows:

```java
    (...)
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "codec")
    private Set<EncodingResult> associatedResults = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "commit_hash", nullable = false, unique = true)
    // indicates the precise version of the codec
    private String commitHash;

    (...)
```

This, however, seems to cause another error: `PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_paitxovhx3j95tuaq9krkk9qh" Detail: Key (commit_hash)=(ec44ee022959410f9596175b9424d9fe1ece9bc8) already exists.`

To my understanding, this must be because the `CascadeType.PERSIST` tries to update the related entities when the parent is updated no matter what (which would make sense, given that in the first `POST` attempt the system works fine, but in the subsequent ones, which do not save `Codec`, for example, if there is already one such entity with the given `commitHash` it doesn't), but I am not sure if this is correct.

Either way, how can I make sure that this operation succeeds? Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do here?

Below is the `JSON` body being used:

```json
{
    "codec": {
        "name": "vvcodec",
        "commitHash": "ec44ee022959410f9596175b9424d9fe1ece9bc8",
        "codecAttrs": "--threads 1",
        "preset": ""
    },
    "video": {
        "name": "bowing_cif",
        "resolution": "352x288",
        "fps": 29.97,
        "nFrames": 300,
        "format": "y4m",
        "uniqueAttrs": "fps29.97_nf300_fy4m_r352x288_nbowing_cif"
    },
    "encodingConfig": {
        "uniqueAttrs": "qp27_nf30_nt8_ca",
        "qp": 27,
        "nFrames": 30,
        "nThreads": 8,
        "codecAttrs": ""
    },
    "ypsnr": 48.2012,
    "upsnr": 49.5337,
    "vpsnr": 51.1360,
    "yuvpsnr": 48.749,
    "bitrate": 196.1958,
    "time": 0.595,
    "energyConsumption": 78.32 
}
```

**EDIT:** I suppose this will also help - my implementation of the `@Service` layer for the given method:

```java
public EncodingResult saveEncodingResult(EncodingResult encodingResult) {
        var video = encodingResult.getVideo();
        var encodingConfig = encodingResult.getEncodingConfig();
        var codec = encodingResult.getCodec();

        if (videoRepository.findByUniqueAttrs(video.getUniqueAttrs()).isEmpty())
            videoRepository.save(video);
        if (encodingConfigRepository.findByUniqueAttrs(encodingConfig.getUniqueAttrs()).isEmpty())
            encodingConfigRepository.save(encodingConfig);
        if (codecRepository.findByCommitHash(codec.getCommitHash()).isEmpty())
            codecRepository.save(codec);

        return encodingResultRepository.save(encodingResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you receive EncodingResult in your controller method? If so, hibernate has no idea that Codec already exists because you're creating a new Codec object every time (well, spring does, by deserializing json). Upon save, hibernate tries to insert new Codec because of CascadeType.ALL instead of using an existing entity.

Typically, you would fetch an existing entity from the database, update it's state and then save it - that is unless you're creating a new entity.

Second thing, if EncodingResult is a child of Codec it really shouldn't have CascadeType.ALL on that relation - apart from being able to insert new Codec when saving EncodingResult, you're also specifying that REMOVE operation will be cascaded from EncodingResult to Codec.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this clears things up. I am, however, still confused in regards to the following: would I have to use a `findBy()` method to check whether that entity exists in the database and then use something like `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` to transfer the data from one to the other. or would I have to set the ID of the old entity into this inserted entity  and then save it? If I just use `save()` I imagine that will conflict with the existing entry, right?

Comment: Yes, copying properties would work, because fetched entity is managed by hibernate, and your entity object is in a 'detached' state (hibernate has no idea about it). I think that this article will clarify things a little bit (https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate) - note that in spring project you can inject an EntityManager and use it in placed where this article mentions session methods. After reading this, try to experiment with entityManager.merge, but to be honest i haven't really used it this way so i can't be certain that it would work as expected.